# apach proxy requests to multiple different subdomains

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a web app at domain1.com which needs to be able to make requests to many different sites, too many to add specific vhost information for each site, what I'd like to be able to do is make a request with the web app to its hosting apache server like this

```
/domain1.com/some/path
/domain2.com/some/path
```

and for it to be send to

```
https://domain1.com/some/path
https://domain2.com/some/path
```

I've tried different settings using apaches ProxyPass but with no success

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That should be able to work with these directives:

```
ProxyPass /domain1.com/ https://domain1.com/
ProxyPass /domain2.com/ https://domain2.com/
```

A request to `https://yourproxy.com/domain1.com/some/path` should then be forwarded on to `https://domain1.com/some/path`.  It is also possible you may need to use some of the SSLProxy* directives from mod_ssl.

**Edit** Based on the comment, you might try this:

```
ProxyPass / http://
```

I just now tried that, and `http://myproxy.com:port1/myserver.com:port2/some/path` was sent on to (and returned from) `http://myserver.com:port2/some/path`.

However, this seems like a bad idea from a security standpoint.  I suppose it does allow the proxy to sit on one side of a firewall and allow the backends to be behind the firewall. I am certainly no web expert, but it just feels a bit sketchy.

Comment: unfortunatley there are far too many domains to setup manually and there will be more added later so I need some sort of wildcard or something, any ideas?

Comment: @tee:  I added a bit more information that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the update but this wouldn't work with my current setup as the proxy also serves a site so when my webpage loads and requests a css file from /my/css/folder/some.css I assume this would be proxied as well to http : //my/css/folder/some.css